# Invalid device Ordinal , CUDA / TORCH

Tags: python, gpu, pytorch

I am getting this error on running the script in ubuntu 16.04 . Please bear with me , i am new to python , 
I have checked the already available options on internet but i couldnt fix it.

```
 RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (10) : invalid device ordinal at torch/csrc/cuda/Module.cpp:32
```

I am currently running this file .

```
from __future__ import print_function
from models import LipRead
import torch
import toml
from training import Trainer
from validation import Validator

print("Loading options...")
with open('options.toml', 'r') as optionsFile:
options = toml.loads(optionsFile.read())

if(options["general"]["usecudnnbenchmark"] and options["general"]    ["usecudnn"]):
print("Running cudnn benchmark...")
torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True

#Create the model.
model = LipRead(options)

if(options["general"]["loadpretrainedmodel"]):
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(options["general"]    ["pretrainedmodelpath"]))

#Move the model to the GPU.
if(options["general"]["usecudnn"]):
model = model.cuda(options["general"]["gpuid"])

trainer = Trainer(options)
validator = Validator(options)

for epoch in range(options["training"]["startepoch"], options["training"]["epochs"]):

if(options["training"]["train"]):
    trainer.epoch(model, epoch)

if(options["validation"]["validate"]):
    validator.epoch(model)
```

And  I doubt this file has something to do with the error popped

```
Title = "TOML Example"

[general]
usecudnn = true
usecudnnbenchmark = true
gpuid = 0
loadpretrainedmodel = true
pretrainedmodelpath = "trainedmodel.pt"
savemodel = true
modelsavepath = "savedmodel.pt"

[input]
batchsize = 18
numworkers = 18
shuffle = true

[model]
type = "LSTM"
inputdim = 256 
hiddendim = 256
numclasses = 500
numlstms = 2

[training]
train = true
epochs = 15
startepoch = 10
statsfrequency = 1000
dataset = "/udisk/pszts-ssd/AV-ASR-data/BBC_Oxford/lipread_mp4"
learningrate = 0.003
momentum = 0.9
weightdecay = 0.0001

[validation]
validate = true
dataset = "/udisk/pszts-ssd/AV-ASR-data/BBC_Oxford/lipread_mp4"
saveaccuracy = true
accuracyfilelocation = "accuracy.txt"
```

The error is mostly in the gpuid line as i have finally reached.

Comment: Whats the error? your post doesn't include the error, also include source code that could produce the error that your getting

Comment: @Lasitha Thanks for ur comment , i was editing the question , See if u can sort it

Comment: Are you certain you have a supported, working GPU? Can you run any of the samples from the CUDA Toolkit correctly?

Comment: Yes , i have used for other codes and they are working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pre-trained weights might be mapped to a different gpuid. If a model pre-trained on multiple Cuda devices is small enough, it might be possible to run it on a single GPU. This is assuming at least batch of size 1 fits in the available GPU and RAM.

```
#WAS
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(final_model_file, map_location={'cuda:0':'cuda:1'}))
#IS
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(final_model_file, map_location={'cuda:0':'cuda:0'}))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this

```
import torch
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

If you get the output to be False, that means PyTorch hasn't detected the GPU. 
I had the same issue and reinstalling Pytorch worked for me.
You might also want to look at this https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/6098 .

Answer (score 2):

You might be getting that error if the pre-trained model is trained on a different number of Cuda devices. For example, while training the model you used 3 Cuda devices and now you are loading the same trained model on a device with only a single Cuda device.

Comment: So, is there a possibility to use a model pre-trained on multiple Cuda devices when only a single one is available?

Comment: Check @rigo answer. You just need to pass the device where you want to load the weights in pytorch. eg net.load_state_dict(torch.load("weight_path.pth", map_location="cuda:0"))